# Very slow UserInput Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a food logger. And i am trying to make a script that allows me to append a row in Sheet[1], and add a new foodsource, should it not already be there. This code here works, but it is very slow to execute. There is about a second in between each question. Is there any possiblity to make the executions faster, or maybe ask for all 4 values in one Prompt?

```
 // Display a dialog box with a title, message, input field, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The
 // user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
function foodSource(){ 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Tilføjelse af madvare', 'Hvilken madvare er det?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return response.getResponseText();
}
function protein(){ 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Protein', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return response.getResponseText();
}
function carbonhydrates(){ 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Kulhydrater', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return response.getResponseText();
}
function fat(){ 
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Fedt', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  return response.getResponseText();
}



function addData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

 sheet.appendRow([madvare(),100, protein(), carbonhydrates(), fat()]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each API call takes a "lot of time" so to speedup a script we should reduce the API calls.

In the code exposed there are three functions that each of one has a call to SpreadsheetApp.getUI. The execution time could be reduced the using only one as it is not changed.

One way to do the above is to integrate this three functions in the fourth one (this was not tested):

```
 // Display a dialog box with a title, message, input field, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The
 // user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.

function addData(){

  /*
   *  Get ui only once
   */
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //Get foodsource
  var response = ui.prompt('Tilføjelse af madvare', 'Hvilken madvare er det?', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var foodsource = response.getResponseText();

  //Get protein
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Protein', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var protein = response.getResponseText();

  // Get carbohydrates
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Kulhydrater', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var carbonhydrates = response.getResponseText();

  //Get fat
  var response = ui.prompt('Mængde pr 100 gram', 'Fedt', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var fat = response.getResponseText();

  //Append a row with the collected data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  sheet.appendRow([foodsource,100, protein, carbonhydrates, fat]); 
}
```